# Cannot execute binaries I import into my Android OS project - getting Permission Denied error

Tags: android, permissions

I have compiled wget to execute on my Pixel 3A XL emulator running Android 10.0.  "file ./wget" (my imported wget binary) shows:

```
file ./wget 
wget: ELF executable, 64-bit LSB x86-64, static, not stripped
```

However, when I call this wget binary in my Android Studio code, I am seeing from "adb logcat":

```
Cannot run program "./wget" (in directory "/data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/files/steve"): error=13, Permission denied
```

The relevant directories have full read/execute permissions set (755).  wget is set to 755 permissions.  What I am wondering is: is SELinux blocking me from running any of my own executables?  And if so, how can I reconfigure it to allow execution of binaries I import?  Or is there something else in play here that would block execution of imported binaries in Android?

thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10?hl=en#execute-permission

Comment: thanks for that link - in it I see this:

Comment: Thanks for that link.  In it it says: "cannot invoke exec() on files within the app's home directory", which is what I was doing.  Does anyone know which dir I can use in Android 10 to execute my binaries?  One statement in that link says, "Apps should load only the binary code that's embedded within an app's APK file.  I don't follow this.  Enlightenment on this latst statement is welcome.

Comment: "Enlightenment on this latst statement is welcome" -- I presume that it is referring to native libraries that you compile into your app using the NDK.

Comment: OK - thanks for that.  I will read up on how to do that next.